# Do I actually need a P60 to file a UK tax return?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom

I want to file my tax return for last tax year as quickly as possible, as I'll be owed a refund.

In the employment section it asks for information from my P60, which typically won't be issued for a few weeks. However, I know the information as the pay/tax are listed on my last payslip from March, and the PAYE reference is on last year's P60. Taxable expenses are reported through payroll, so I'm not expecting a P11D.

Will I be breaking any rules or storing up any trouble for myself if I file my return before receiving my P60?

[Technically the return talks about either a P60 or a P45, but the latter would only be relevant if I'd left the job during the last tax year]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question. I would say that if you only have one employer, have been employed by them for the entire tax year in question, and have not had any "off-nominal" circumstances (weird share scheme arrangement or something) then the information on your last payslip of the year and your P60 should be the same. I just checked mine for the last two years and they are the same (before that I had maternity leave which complicates things). You could check  yours for previous years and see whether they line up similarly.

The harder part would be the P11D I would have thought. I typically don't get my P11D until August but I would not be able to complete the tax return without it. The only relevant benefit is that my company pays for private medical insurance, but I can't calculcate or determine the cost of that without the P11D.

Comment: They do line up - and I don't get a P11D as my employer pushes all benefits through my pay slip - e.g. medical insurance is done by crediting £X on the gross side and debiting £X on the net side.

Comment: I did this and nothing went wrong, so I think it's fine if you do know the numbers (P11D indeed being a potential complication).

Comment: I also asked an HMRC adviser about this in passing when calling about something else, and he confirmed you can submit without a P60. Not definitive, but further evidence for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

On the latest occasion that my income tax office sent me their (very long) printed guide to how to fill in my tax return, it specifically mentioned my not needing to include any documents or payslips when submitting the form.

If one is an employee, the Inland Revenue will already know from PAYE all about your earnings, all of which are taxed at source before you receive them, so the one thing they *never* ask to see is your P60 annual summary.

Comment: I know they won't want to see it routinely, but I'm slightly worried about  breaking some rule about filling in the return.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam pretty sure HMRC don't care whether you physically have the P60 or not - they care that you give them correct information.

The only slight risk is if for some reason there is a discrepancy between your last pay slip and the P60.  Even then I *think* you can amend your tax return after submission, but it's probably worth checking on the details of that.